# Zero shallow heap, non-zero retained heap

Tags: android, garbage-collection

When I analyse the hprof file with MAT, there is an object with zero shallow heap. However its retained heap is 48 Bytes. Is this a weak reference ? Is its  memory reclaimed by GC ? Thanks

Comment: Retained heap is nothing but objects that are reference to the first object, directly or indirectly, only from those original object.